# Python Self is not defined issue

Tags: python-2.7, undefined, self

I've got the following Python class which insists *self* is not defined even though I'm using it prior to the line causing the error.

The error:

```
File "/home/sisko/moveit_ws/src/ur5bot_moveit_config/nodes/test.py", line 35, in Test
end_effector_link = self.arm.get_end_effector_link()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import moveit_commander
import rospy
from copy import deepcopy

class Test():
  """docstring for Test"""
  def __init__(self):
    rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface_tutorial', anonymous=False)

    # declarations
    self.robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
    self.arm = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander('manipulator')

    joint_positions = [0.2 ,-0.5, 1.57, -1.0, -0.4, 0.5]
    self.arm.set_joint_value_target(joint_positions)
    self.arm.go()

    rospy.sleep(5)

    self.arm.set_named_target('up')
    self.arm.go()

    rospy.sleep(5)

    self.arm.set_named_target('home')
    self.arm.go()


    # Get the name of the end-effector link
    end_effector_link = self.arm.get_end_effector_link()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  t = Test()
```

Comment: What happens when you replace that line with `print self`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: I got <__main__.Test instance at 0xb7c7f22c> when I printed self

Comment: And when you change it back?

Comment: Same error. I just placed the print self line above the line generating the error. The print statement only prints when the 'error' line is commented out.

Comment: Did you retype it, or use some undo feature of your editor? My only guess is that there are some strange non-printable characters in that line. But even if so, if the print is *before* that line, it should be executed.

Comment: @mkrieger1: That's so annoyingly correct. I collapsed the tab spacings and re-tabbed everything and the error has gone away. Thank you. If you want to provide an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.